# How do I upload an image using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, hybrid-mobile-app

How do I upload an image and store it into a cookie? I want to be able to upload an image with limitations on e.g. file size restrictions.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

In this code is the function to upload a file with restrictions on.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="bitnami.css" media="all" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="test.php"/>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i do not think you can put a whole image on a cookie o.o

Comment: How would I go about saving the image?

Comment: Despite I can't really imagine of a scenario where this should be useful, it actually **is** possible to safe an image into a cookie via `base64_encode()`

Comment: @Icefyre nonsense? O.o i've stated (i do not think). That said  you can check the size with html alone (but the user can skip it). You can google to see how php can block an upload if the image size (as KB) are too big or if the dimension (width/height) it's too big.

Comment: @MarcoMura Sorry for the misconception. The 'nonsense' was actually based on OP's intention, not on your comment.

Comment: @Icefyre thanks for the clarification :) That said there are a lot of ways to do what he want Oo

Comment: @Icefyre My question is a valid question... it is not 'nonsense'

Comment: @Garrett Oohm! What I actually meant with 'nonsense' (which I already changed for clarification's sake by the way) wasn't the question itself (questioning is good!), but the intention behind it. There should be no reason at all to save an image into a cookie.

Comment: @Icefyre I am testing how to upload images... how would you go about it? The 'base64_encode()'?

Comment: Just don't do such a thing like saving an image into a cookie... if you want to do it properly, see the solution @MarcB provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple faults in your logic.

1) You never check if an upload was actually performed. You just start working on the `['tmp_name']` without ever checking if it actually exists. Your **FIRST** action on processing an upload must be to check for errors:

```
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']);
}
```

2) You're checking file types based on filename extensions. Nothing says a user can't do `ren nastyvirus.exe cutekittens.jpg` and get through your filename check. You're already using `getimagesize()` later on, so the extension check is pointless:

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);

if ($info === false) {
    die("Not an image at all");
}

if (($info[2] != IMGTYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] != IMGTYPE_JPG) && ($info[2] != IMGTYPE_PNG)) {
   die("Not a gif/jpg/png");
}

if (($info[0] > $maximum_width) || ($info[1] > $maximum_height)) {
   die("Too tall/wide");
}
```

And then, after all that - why store it in a cookie? Cookies are naturally limited in the maximum amount of data that can be stored. You shouldn't exect to be able to store more than a couple kilobytes at most. Since you've set your upload size limit at 500k, you WILL end up with corrupted/truncated images if you do store a 500k into that 1-2k cookie.

Comment: Thanks! :) Did you dislike my question down?

Comment: I'd suggest to use `IMAGETYPE_*` instead of `IMG_*`, as there are some known bugs related to `IMG_*`. Also, please always have in mind that the third index (2) of `getimagesize()` will only provide the type specified in client's http header and therefore should never be relied on when it comes to security.

Comment: @ice: uh, what? getimagesize retrieves data directly from the file. it couldn't care less what the client said in the upload headers. gis() doesn't know WHERE the image came from, it only looks at the on-disk data. Good point on the imagetype constants tho. fixing that.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I messed something up. Anyway, relying on it was exploitable in the past, see http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/; I don't know if it's still applicable though.

Comment: not really an exploit in there. You can embed PHP in ANY file you want. After all, there's no such thing as a "php script". There's only files which have `<?php ... ?>` code blocks within them. And a proper upload handling system that accepts uploads from abitrary users would NEVER use the client-provided filename anyways. You'd store the file using some other name (e.g. db primary key ID) and store the user's filename in the db.